# Updating MySQL table with a PHP script

Tags: php, mysql

I am developing an android application, where I want to insert the address of the user to the database calling a PHP script on a website.

In the first try, it has to insert the address into the database and after that, it has update the same tuple.

This is the PHP script I have, but it gives an error in line number 36 (Call to a member function bind_param()).

Nevertheless, insertion is working perfectly fine.

```
class DbOperations1{

    private $con;
    function __construct(){

        require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/DbConnect.php';

    $db = new DbConnect();
    $this->con = $db->connect();
    }

    public function createUser ($name, $email, $password) {
        if($this->isUserExist($name, $email))
        {
            return 0;
        }else{
            $password = md5($password);
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `test` (`id`,`name`, `email`, `password`) VALUES (NULL, ? , ? , ? );"); 
            $stmt->bind_param ("sss", $name, $email, $password);

            if ($stmt->execute()){
                return 1;
            } else {
                return 2;
            }
        }

    }

    public function Address($id_user, $address, $road, $city, $country) {
        if($this->isAddressExist($id_user, $address))
        {   
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE address a, users u SET `address`=$address,`road`=$road,`city`=$city,`country`=$country WHERE a.id_user=u.id"); 
            $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $address, $road, $city, $country);
            if ($stmt->execute()){
                return 2;
            } else {
                return 3;
            }
        }else{
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `address` (`id_address`, `id_user`,`address`, `road`, `city`, `country`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ? , ? ,? ,? );"); 
            $stmt->bind_param ("sssss", $id_user, $address, $road, $city, $country);

            if ($stmt->execute()){
                return 0;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }

    }

        public function userLogin($email, $password){
        $password = md5($password);
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = ? AND password = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss",$email,$password);
        $stmt->execute();
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0; 
        }

        public function getUserByemail($email){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s",$email);
        $stmt->execute();
        return $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
    }

        private function isUserExist($name, $email){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id FROM test WHERE name = ? OR email = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("ss", $name, $email);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0; 
    }

        private function isAddressExist($id_user){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT id_address FROM address WHERE id_user = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $id_user);
        $stmt->execute(); 
        $stmt->store_result(); 
        return $stmt->num_rows > 0; 
    }


}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Call to a member function bind_param(), In the public function Address in the updating query.

Comment: I was asking about error message content, not location.

Comment: "Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on boolean in C:\wamp64\www\android\includes\DbOperations1.php on line 36" this is the error

Comment: Good. So it means, that your call to `prepare` failed and returned `False`.

Comment: nice to hear that, I want to know what is wrong there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comments, the error is because of call to `prepare` failing.
Following code will allow to get more info:

```
        if($this->isAddressExist($id_user, $address))
        {   
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE address a, users u SET `address`=$address,`road`=$road,`city`=$city,`country`=$country WHERE a.id_user=u.id");
            if($stmt != False) {
              $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $address, $road, $city, $country);
              if ($stmt->execute()){
                  return 2;
              } else {
                  return 3;
              }
            } else {
              // this line will give an insight into an error message
              echo $this->con->error;
            }
        }
```

After getting the error message from MySQL:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'road=Sarak,city=Khost,country=Afghanistan WHERE a.id_user= 10' at line 1
```

we locate exact error location and there is `$address` variable used, while it shall be `?`! Such statement can't be prepared.

Using following update statement should fix it:

```
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE address a, users u SET `address`=?,`road`=?,`city`=?,`country`=? WHERE a.id_user=u.id");
```

Comment: It can't be. Have you added `if($stmt != False)` after the call to `prepare`?

Comment: $stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE address a, users u SET `address`=$address,`road`=$road,`city`=$city,`country`=$country WHERE a.id_user= $id_user");

Comment: i edited the code as its shown in above comment, but still i ma getting the error as: "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`road`=Sarak,`city`=Khost,`country`=Afghanistan WHERE a.id_user= 10' at line 1{"error":true,"message":"Address is inserted"}"

Comment: Great! That was the point of the above code, to get error message from MySQL!

Comment: thanks, a little more assistance from you may make the script work. :)

Comment: I've expanded my answer, try it.

Comment: this query works in MySQL but it doesn't work in the PHP script, I will share the second script as well from I am passing the values to DbOperations.

Comment: Have you swapped all variables inside the query with `?`? No need to share another script, unless you can provide minimal example which is not working correctly, but does not contain all unnecessary code.

Comment: user2328995 has just pointed out to that, thank you for the cooperation. much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
public function Address($id_user, $address, $road, $city, $country) {
        if($this->isAddressExist($id_user))
    {   
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE address SET `address`=?,`road`=?,`city`=?,`country`=? WHERE id_user= ?");
        if($stmt != False) {
          $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $address, $road, $city, $country,$id_user);
          if ($stmt->execute()){
              return 2;
          } else {
              return 3;
          }
        } else {
          // hopefully this line will give an insight into an error message
          echo $this->con->error;
        }
    } else{
            $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO `address` (`id_address`, `id_user`,`address`, `road`, `city`, `country`) VALUES (NULL, ?, ? , ? ,? ,? );"); 
            $stmt->bind_param ("sssss", $id_user, $address, $road, $city, $country);

            if ($stmt->execute()){
                return 0;
            } else {
                return 1;
            }
        }

    }
```

This should work. When it comes to parameter binding you have to use ? (question mark ) instead of the parameter name and bind the parameters by name in the correct order in bind_param function.

Answer (score 0):

```
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE address SET `address`=$address,`road`=$road,`city`=$city,`country`=$country WHERE a.id_user=u.id");
```

try to update one table

Comment: No need to update single table. Syntax wise, its possible to update multiple table like this.

Comment: I am updating one table, but in the where condition I need to compare the keys of the two tables.

Comment: $stmt = $this->con->prepare("UPDATE address, user  SET `address`=$address,`road`=$road,`city`=$city,`country`=$country WHERE a.id_user=u.id");

Comment: address a, users u is being done to refer to each tables tuples in where conditions as a.id_user and u.id for comparison. what u have commented is wrong.